# Drupal Media Library - File Upload Library shows “No files available.”

Tags: views, media

I am actualy running in some sort of strange problem. I installed Media 7.x-2.x-alpha2. I can upload files without any problems. When I go to "admin/content/file" I see the uploaded files.

[image]

Now comes the problem, when I want to add a image via the library dialog, while creating a new node, the box shows me "No files available.".
[image]

I checked the media browser view and the very strange is, that the files shows up in there

[image]

I tried updating to newest dev release and checked the permissions, but anything looks just fine. I am working as user 1.

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 2):

Answer from basti:

> The problem could be solved by removing the Query Tag under "Query settings" inside the view options. I have no idea why, but after removing it, anything works just fine.

Comment: Confirming that this works (tested with 7.x-2.x-alpha4).